# What is this gray hydronic tubing and how should I work with it?

Tags: plumbing, hydronic

I purchased a house (built in California in 1994) with radiant hydronic floors. This tubing comes from the floors in the utility room and it appears to be using compression fittings to connect to the main circulation manifold.
It is not PEX. It's 1/2" OD.

What sort of tubing is this? Does it use standard compression fittings? Is there anything about it that might not be intuitive to work with?

I am familiar with most advanced DIY plumbing, copper soldering, PEX etc.

I want to perform some maintenance and reorganizing but I would like to try and be prepared with all the parts I think I might need in advance.

Edit: using digital calipers I measured the OD at 1/2" and the ID at 3/8"
Thus I can't see any dimensions which make it distinguishable.

[image: tube]
[image: od]

Comment: Grey pipe might be PB polybuylene pipe or a few other types, PVC.  PB pipes went out of use after 95 because of lawsuits.  Do you have longer pieces with markings?

Comment: @crip659 I didn't see any "dead giveaway" markings on the stubs coming from the slab but I also didn't know what to look for. What sort of markings should I look for?

Comment: Not quite sure, but think most plastic pipe have what they are made of, marked on them, PVC, ABS, Poly-B.  Have a bit of marking in the top picture.  Might google for plastic burn test.

Comment: Provide pics of the markings on any visible parts of the pipe. While you may not recognize anything, it's highly likely that someone here will.

Answer (score 1):

Gray is very frequently polybutylene, and polybutylene is a problem. Which is why it's not used anymore. You can get transition and retrofit fittings for it still. Indeed, the fittings themselves might be a way of confirming that it's PB (as would piecing together more of the text on the side of the tube.)

OD and wall thickness look to be consistent with 3/8" PB, which is [.500" OD and 1/16" wall.](https://www.sizes.com/materials/pipe_polybutylene.htm)

Comment: Reading up on it, mine is closed loop hydronic encased in slab so I feel mostly safe from the failure mode hypotheses

Comment: Are there alternate fitting types that can be used with PB in lieu of the acetal junk that gave PB its bad name? (say something like a modern PEX fitting?)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel PB itself fractures. It's not just the fittings as your comment implies. As a hydronic loop it is somewhat isolated form the usual main cause of that, however. The usual overpriced suspects appear to make "push-in" fittings if you prefer those.

Comment: I have ordered one fitting designed to fit on the 3/8 tubing based on the dimensions in your link. I'll accept your answer assuming it fits. Thanks!

Comment: So the sharkbite fits because the OD is 0.5" same as PEX. However, I used calipers to measure the tubing thickness and it's 2mm = .0787 inches. This makes it seem more like PEX. Is there an alternative way to tell them apart?

Comment: Technically, the spec is 'minimum 0.062" wall' so 0.079" exceeds the spec. Gray is highly unusual for PEX. As already stated, the text on the side of the tube is going to be the best way to positively identify it.